# Mathematica 10 unable to Simplify[Cos[2 ArcCos[A]]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Mathematica 10 evaluates `Simplify[Cos[2 ArcCos[A]]]` as `Cos[2 ArcCos[A]]`, instead of the desired `2 A^2 - 1`. How do I go about making this reduction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `TrigExpand`

```
TrigExpand[Cos[2 ArcCos[A]]]
```

> ```
> -1 + 2 A^2
> ```

Comment: Comment: situations like this, where specialized functions such as `TrigExpand` or `TrigToExp` are needed, often pop up. They are seemingly counterexamples to one of the *Mathematica* core principles: "Automate as much as possible."  (http://www.wolfram.com/language/principles/)